# let ngIf sort elements according to their beginning letter

Tags: html, angular, ionic3

I have an list of names, and I would like to sort them by their beginning letter. Therefore I wrote buttons to select the first letter of the name. Now I would like to show only the names beginning with the selected letter using ngIf.

```
<button *ngFor = "let letter of alphabet" (click)="showSelectedLetter(letter)">{{letter}}</button>
  <div *ngFor="let name of names">
    <button *ngIf="name.startswith(letter)"> // Pseudocode
      // only names beginning with "letter" are shown
    </button>
  </div>
```

My question, is there something like the Pseudocode `*ngIf="name.startswith(letter)` I used to preselect the items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created this Stackblitz for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ujnsur

component.ts

```
  public alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  public names = ['aname', 'bname', 'cname'];
  public selectedLetter;

  showSelectedLetter(letter: string) {
    this.selectedLetter = letter;
  }

  filterByFirstLetter(name) {
    return name.slice(0,1) === this.selectedLetter;
  }
```

component.html

```
<button *ngFor = "let letter of alphabet" (click)="showSelectedLetter(letter)">{{letter}}</button>
  <div *ngFor="let name of names">
    <div *ngIf="filterByFirstLetter(name)">
      {{name}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

It does what you have requested but for this type of thing you should be using a custom pipe: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is concept of Pipe to sort your elements. 
Use it like

```
<button *ngFor = "let letter of (alphabet|sortByAlphabets)"></button>
```

And create pipe `sortByAlphabets` using `ng g p sortByAlphabets` command.

Write your sorting logic in newly created `sortByAlphabets` pipe.

your `sortByAlphabets.pipe.ts` file will look like,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

import { Flyer } from './heroes';

@Pipe({ name: 'sortByAlphabets' })
export class SortByAlphabetsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array) {
    return array.sort();
  }
}
```